# UIButton text color with RGB

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am creating a `UIButton` programically according the following mentioned code block. I need to assign RGB color to the text of the button. Its not applying. Any particular reason?

```
  CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(353, y, 607, 30);
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
    button.tag = event.eventId;
    [button setTitle:event.eventName forState: UIControlStateNormal];
     button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:14];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:10.0 green:20.0 blue:100.0 alpha:1.0] forState: UIControlEventAllEvents];
    [self.contentView addSubview:button];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

RGB values need to be in the range 0.0 to 1.0. Divide each of your numbers by 255.0.

Answer (score 2):

here is your reason :

**write**

```
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:10.0/255.0 green:20.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState: UIControlEventAllEvents];
```

**Instead of** just

`[button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:10.0 green:20.0 blue:100.0 alpha:1.0] forState: UIControlEventAllEvents];`

Enjoy Programming..

Answer (score 1):

```
// no need to alloc UIButton.. 

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(353, y, 607, 30);
button.tag = event.eventId;
[button setTitle:event.eventName forState: UIControlStateNormal];
 button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:14];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:10.0/255.0 green:20.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[self.contentView addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed%3agreen%3ablue%3aalpha%3a) the color values range from 0.0 to 1.0, so You should divide the current values with their max possible value usually 255 like this:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:10.0/255.0 green:20.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState: UIControlEventAllEvents];
```